# My package's new updateinfo.xml shows up in the yum cache, but isn't displayed as a security update by yum update

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, yum

I have a package I want to release a security update for. So I added an updateinfo.xml and used `modifyrepo` to add it to the files listed by `repomd.xml`. When I test with the `baseurl` of the yum repo config pointed locally, I can verify that `yum` does download the new updateinfo.xml: it shows up in `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/MYAPP/gen/updateinfo.xml`.

Additionally, since I bumped the version number, running `yum install MYAPP` says there's a version update waiting. But I've tried the following commands and none of them list any security updates, even though the updateinfo.xml has `type=security` in the `update` tag.

`$ yum updateinfo MYAPP
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
updateinfo info done`

Note that my package is not in these mirrors; it is a local repo specified in `/etc/yum.repos.d/MYAPP.repo`.

The `updateinfo.xml` is as follows. I used https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Standards_Rpm_Metadata_UpdateInfo as an example (and fixed some xml syntax errors) so some of the text is not updated yet.

`<updates>
  <update from="rel-eng@fedoraproject.org" status="stable" type="security" version="1.4">
    <id>MYAPP</id>
    <title>MYAPP</title>
    <release>MYAPP</release>
    <issued date="2018-12-05 00:00:00"/>
    <references>
      <reference href="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=426091" id="426091" title="CVE-2007-3568 imlib: infinite loop DoS using crafted BMP image" type="bugzilla"/>
      <reference href="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=426091" id="426091" title="CVE-2007-3568 imlib: infinite loop DoS using crafted BMP image" type="cve"/>
    </references>
    <description>THIS update includes a fix for a denial-of-service issue (CVE-2007-3568) whereby an attacker who could get an imlib-using user to view a  specially-crafted BMP imag</description>
    <pkglist>
      <collection short="F8">
        <name>MYAPP</name>
        <package arch="x84_64" name="MYAPP" release="MYAPPVERSION" src="">
          <filename>MYAPP-MYAPPVERSION.rpm</filename>
          <reboot_suggested>True</reboot_suggested>
        </package>
      </collection>
    </pkglist>
  </update>
</updates>`

any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a misunderstanding with the `pkglist`. I had to specify the versions that fixed the problem (the new version), not the old one.